Halcon, hom_mat3d to hom_mat2d
Having already the elements of hom_mat3d matrix at hand, how to extract 2d-translation, 2d-rotation and 2d-scaling as part of it? I understand that hom_mat3d is performed in 3d, but as 2d-space is subspace of 3d, I assume that one can find the 2d-translation, 2d-scale and 2d-rotation from the hom_mat3d in Halcon.
Or maybe I am wrong?
Thanks for helps!
I tried different elements of hom_mat3d but no results so far.
